# Save an RGB24 sample to bitmap

Tags: visual-c++, ms-media-foundation

I'm using Windows Media Foundation to do some messing around with my webcam. I've been able to successfully retrieve a data sample from the webcam and identify that the format is RGB24. Now I'd like to save a single frame as a bitmap. A small snippet of the code I'm using to read a sample from the webcam is below.

```
IMFSample *pSample = NULL;

hr = pReader->ReadSample(
   MF_SOURCE_READER_ANY_STREAM,    // Stream index.
   0,                              // Flags.
   &streamIndex,                   // Receives the actual stream index. 
   &flags,                         // Receives status flags.
   &llTimeStamp,                   // Receives the time stamp.
   &pSample                        // Receives the sample or NULL.
 );
```

So once I've got pSample populated with an IMFSample how can I save it as a bitmap?

Comment: Use IMFSample::ConvertToContinguousBuffer() to get a IMFMediaBuffer interface pointer.  QI it for IMF2DBuffer.  Then use its Lock2D() method to get a pointer to the pixel data.

Comment: I can now get that far. Any pointers on how to save the IMF2DBuffer to a bitmap file? I'm searching around but haven't found a solution as yet.

Comment: No matter I managed to kludge something together. I'll post my code sample as an answer after removing some of the nastiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code snippet I used to save a bitmap from an IMFSample. I've taken a lot of shortcuts and I'm pretty sure I'm only able to get away with doing things this way because my webcam defaults to returning an RGB24 stream and also a 640 x 480 pixel buffer which means there's no striping to worry about in pData.

```
   hr = pReader->ReadSample(
    MF_SOURCE_READER_ANY_STREAM,    // Stream index.
    0,                              // Flags.
    &streamIndex,                   // Receives the actual stream index. 
    &flags,                         // Receives status flags.
    &llTimeStamp,                   // Receives the time stamp.
    &pSample                        // Receives the sample or NULL.
    );

wprintf(L"Stream %d (%I64d)\n", streamIndex, llTimeStamp);

HANDLE file;
BITMAPFILEHEADER fileHeader;
BITMAPINFOHEADER fileInfo;
DWORD write = 0;

file = CreateFile(L"sample.bmp",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);  //Sets up the new bmp to be written to

fileHeader.bfType = 19778;                                                                    //Sets our type to BM or bmp
fileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(fileHeader.bfOffBits) + sizeof(RGBTRIPLE);                                                //Sets the size equal to the size of the header struct
fileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;                                                                    //sets the reserves to 0
fileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
fileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);                    //Sets offbits equal to the size of file and info header

fileInfo.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
fileInfo.biWidth = 640;
fileInfo.biHeight = 480;
fileInfo.biPlanes = 1;
fileInfo.biBitCount = 24;
fileInfo.biCompression = BI_RGB;
fileInfo.biSizeImage = 640 * 480 * (24/8);
fileInfo.biXPelsPerMeter = 2400;
fileInfo.biYPelsPerMeter = 2400;
fileInfo.biClrImportant = 0;
fileInfo.biClrUsed = 0;

WriteFile(file,&fileHeader,sizeof(fileHeader),&write,NULL);
WriteFile(file,&fileInfo,sizeof(fileInfo),&write,NULL);

IMFMediaBuffer *mediaBuffer = NULL;
    BYTE *pData = NULL;

pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&mediaBuffer);

hr = mediaBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, NULL);

WriteFile(file, pData, fileInfo.biSizeImage, &write, NULL);

CloseHandle(file);

mediaBuffer->Unlock();
```

I've included a bit of a discussion [here](http://blog.sipsorcery.com/building-a-video-softphone-part-iii/).

Comment: Is bitmap file headers required? Can I simply save RGB24 data to a bitmap file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the headers for the file to be recognised by other applications otherwise it would be just raw pixel data and it would be impossible to know where the rows and columns started.